# Mocking an ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, objectinputstream

When i try to mock ObjectInputStream object i get a NullPointerException.
More precisely, when this line is called: `when(inputStream.readObject()).thenReturn(new Person("Doe", "John", "123"));`

Code fragment:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConnectionTest{
  ...
  @Mock
  private ObjectInputStream inputStream;
  ...
  @Test
  public void test(){
   ...
    when(inputStream.readObject()).thenReturn(new Person("Doe", "John", "123"));
  ...
  }
}
```

Normally, when you initialize ObjectInputStream you have to pass an InputStream object as a constructor argument and i bet this is the problem here - there's no InputStream assigned to the ObjectInputStream.

How should i mock the ObjectInputStream properly then?

Comment: Unrelated: next time, put up an [mcve]. Just by **leaving out** the ... in your question, and have thenReturn return a simple string for example - you would allow your readers to just copy/paste your code to repro yourself. Dont put anything in your example code that **prevents** users from running it - especially when asking for something that is really about "these lines of code not working".

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept. For the record: besides using other mocking frameworks (which I actually recommend to **not** do) - see my updated answer for another approach. Feel free to ask questions if you need further help (where I am dropping the pen for today).

Comment: It's all good now. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that [readObject()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()) is **final**.

Mockito can't mock **final** methods. So what happens is that the attempt to *specify* that call for the mock object ... simply goes wrong. And yes, the fact that an NPE gets thrown is more than  misleading.

You can try to use that *[experimental](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39)* feature in Mockito 2 that allows mocking *final* methods. If that doesn't work for you, PowerMock(ito) or JMockit most likely would do the job.

And just for the record: such subtle problems are yet another good reason to not use Java built-in serialization any more.

The only other way to bypass this: program against the corresponding **interface** [ObjectInput](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInput.html), not the specific implementation class.

As you can easily mock that *interface*.

But of course, that means changing your production code. Which might not be a bad idea, as it **decouples** your business logic from the *actual* form of serialization. If you later choose to serialize as JSON strings, using GSON - you would just replace the implementation of that interface.

Answer (score 3):

As the others stated `readObject()` is `final` in `ObjectInputStream`.

I appreciate that the others did suggest <strike>PowerMock</strike> to force a mock of this class!

The better solution is to follow that *program against interfaces* pattern. The method `readObject()` is declared in the interface `ObjectInput` implemented by  `ObjectInputStream` So you can change the signature of your class to use the interface `ObjectInput` rather than the concrete class  `ObjectInputStream`.

And mocking the interface `ObjectInput` is a piece of cake...

---

> could you add an MCVE of how this is meant to look like? Nobody did this so far. – Tobias Kolb

here it is:

#### production code:

```
public class Person {
    public Person(String string, String string2, String string3) {
    }
}

class ClassUnderTest {
    private final ObjectInput objectInput;

    public ClassUnderTest(ObjectInput inputStream) {
        objectInput = inputStream;
    }

    public Person readFromObjectStreamAsSideEffect() {
        try {
            return (Person) objectInput.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("some meaningful explanation.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Test code

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // allows for other runner...
public class ConnectionTest {

    @Mock
    ObjectInput inputStream;

    // @InjectMocks
    // compiler will NOT complain if constructor arguments are missing, so I discourage this.

    ClassUnderTest cut; // do not initialize here, mock is still NULL.

    @BeforeEach
    private void setup() {
        cut = new ClassUnderTest(inputStream);
    }

    @Test
    public void getPreparedObjectFromInputStreamy() throws Exception {
        Person preparedValueObject = new Person("Doe", "John", "123");
        when(inputStream.readObject()).thenReturn(preparedValueObject);

        Person result = cut.readFromObjectStreamAsSideEffect();

        assertEquals(preparedValueObject, result, "hint for reason of failing");
    }   
}
```

---

> my particular problem is with writeObject(). Specifically `verify(serverInstance).ObjectOutPutStreamToClient.writeObject(someValue);` Do you have a nifty solution for this as well? I recon this is harder because `writeObject` is `void`. – Tobias Kolb

I's not me but Mockito having a solution for this:

#### Production code

```
public class Person {
    public Person(String string, String string2, String string3) {
    }
    // having toString() too improves fail message of test.
}

class ClassUnderTest {
    private final ObjectOutput objectOutput;

    public ClassUnderTest(ObjectOutput objectOutputStream) {
        objectOutput = objectOutputStream;
    }

    public void writeObjects(List<Person> persons) {
        try {
            for (Person person : persons) {
                objectOutput.writeObject(person);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("some meaningfull explanation.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

#### test code

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ConnectionTest {

    @Mock
    ObjectOutput outputStream;

    ClassUnderTest cut;

    @BeforeEach
    private void setup() {
        cut = new ClassUnderTest(outputStream);
    }

    @Test
    public void getPreparedObjectFromInputStreamy() throws Exception {
        List<Person> listToWrite = Arrays.asList(//
                new Person("Doe", "John", "123"),
                new Person("Doe", "Jane", "456"));

        cut.writeObjects(listToWrite);

        ArgumentCaptor<Person> passedArgument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
        verify(outputStream, times(listToWrite.size())).writeObject(passedArgument.capture());
        assertTrue(passedArgument.getAllValues().contains(listToWrite.get(0)), "hint for reason of failing");
        assertTrue(passedArgument.getAllValues().contains(listToWrite.get(1)), "hint for reason of failing");
    }   
}
```

Comment: Ah, there is an interface for that. Forgot about it!

Comment: could you add an MCVE of how this is meant to look like? Nobody did this so far.

Comment: @TobiasKolb: done. BTW: yours is response 1'111 on my list... ;o)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle This is beautiful, although my particular problem is with writeObject().
Specifically `verify(serverInstance).ObjectOutPutStreamToClient.writeObject(someValue);`

Do you have a nifty solution for this as well?
I recon this is harder because writeObject is void.

Comment: @TobiasKolb: you might have added your own question refering this here...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle true. Should I set up my own question?

Comment: Do I absolutely have to pass an OOS to the classes constructor in order to mock it? Because I don't and I would rather initialise it in the class under test (Server), since I don't need it anywhere else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55326244/how-to-mock-objectoutputstream-writeobject here we go @TimothyTruckle

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mock a `final` method as it is not overridable and`readObject()` is `final` :

```
public final Object readObject(){...}
```

To achieve your goal, you could refactor your actual code.
For example you could introduce a wrapper class that hold a `ObjectInputStream` instance and that delegate processing to it.
In this way you could mock the `readObject()` method of this wrapper class.
You could also use Powermock that provides more features than Mockito but sincerely I avoid using it.